# HMVC e a Componentização do HTML

Tags: php, html

Eu já li vários artigos sobre HMVC, tanto em PHP como em outras linguagens, e em todos eles a implementação do padrão girava em torno de se ter um "Controller-mestre" o qual requisitava o *Response Body* de um ou mais recursos, internos ou externos, via cURL ou *Stream Contexts*, a fim de montar o seu próprio, diretamente num objeto responsável pela Resposta, ou através de uma View Engine própria, criando variáveis de template com o(s) HTML obtido(s).

Porém, todos esses artigos se apegavam muito ao conceito técnico e por vezes não abrangiam todos os pontos pertinentes. Com isso a conclusão a que eu pude chegar foi a de que o conceito básico do HMVC é, a grosso modo, MVCs dentro de MVCs, os quais funcionam tanto hierárquica quanto isoladamente, sempre da mesma forma.

Mas como exatamente ocorreria a componentização do HTML desse "Controller-mestre" se, para que cada subsistema funcione da mesma forma **em todos os sentidos** seriam necessários eventuais scripts, folhas de estilo ou mesmo marcações adicionais?

Com um exemplo fica mais fácil de entender:

Considerando uma aplicação cuja GUI seria desenvolvida com o Bootstrap e composta por N componentes, todos também desenvolvidos com o mesmo *framework* (para que isoladamente funcionem igual a aplicação principal), com um HMVC figurativamente criado pelo pseudo-código abaixo:

```
// Make the Requests

$projects = new Request( 'management/projects', 'GET' );
$clients  = new Request( 'management/clients',  'GET' );

// Creates the Template Variables with Response Bodies HTML

$this -> view -> assign(

    array(

        'projects' => $projects -> send(),
        'clients'  =>  $clients -> send()
    )
);
```

> A título de clarificação desse fragmento, *Request::send()* estaria retornando o HTML

Resultaria num HTML similar a:

```
<html lang="en">

    <head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <link rel="stylesheet"
        href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    </head>

    <body>

        <div class="container-fluid">

            <!-- Sidebar -->

            <div class="row">

                <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-2 sidebar" id="sidebar" role="navigation">

                    <ul>
                        <li>Sidebar Item</li>
                        <li>Sidebar Item</li>
                        <li>Sidebar Item</li>
                    </ul>

                </div>

            </div>

            <!-- Main Content -->

            <div class="col-sm-9 col-sm-offset-3 col-md-10 col-md-offset-2 main">

                <html lang="en">

                    <head>

                        <meta charset="utf-8">

                        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

                    </head>

                    <body>

                        <div class="container-fluid">Component HTML</div>

                    </body>

                </html>

            </div>

        </div>

    </body>

</html>
```

O que nesse exemplo simples é "apenas" incorreto, afinal, numa aplicação real poderíamos ter conflito de script, ou regras CSS que fazem uso do **!important** bagunçando com o HTML existente *depois* da seção designada para o componente (um rodapé, por exemplo) e etc.

Sendo assim, como que deveria ocorrer a componentização do HTML num HMVC?

A menor idéia que me ocorre seria a de o "Controller-mestre" analisar o HTML de retorno e pegar só aquilo que estivesse dentro do do `<body></body>`, mas eu não vi nada nem remotamente similar a isso naquilo que eu pesquisei.

Comment: O Kohana tem um modelo HMVC. [*Esse link*](http://techportal.inviqa.com/2010/02/22/scaling-web-applications-with-hmvc/) tem algumas considerações sobrer HMVC.

Comment: Mas você viu que em momento algum ele toca no problema da dúvida que eu levantei? No artigo a construção do tal *Gazouillement* apenas demonstra a técnica de composição, mas não abrange como o HTML final ficaria. A *View* que ele constrói com os dados recebido não especifica esses *Response Bodies* já vêm limpos de quaisquer marcações desnecessárias para Aplicação principal ou se algo mais está sendo feito.

Comment: Por que HMVC e não SOA ?

Comment: Talvez porque eu não saiba muito mais do que apenas a definição de SOA. u.u'

Answer (score 1):

[Bruno Augusto](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/250/bruno-augustor), os componentes HTML podem ser organizados, na estrutura HMVC, em script's separados. 
Ou seja, separe o template da sua aplicação dos scripts HTML referentes ao conteúdo.

Com base no exemplo que você citou, você teria algo como:

Um arquivo para o layout, que como no seu exemplo seria as questões equivalentes em todos os subsistemas.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <!-- Sidebar -->
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-2 sidebar" id="sidebar" role="navigation">
                <ul>
                    <li>Sidebar Item</li>
                    <li>Sidebar Item</li>
                    <li>Sidebar Item</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Main Content -->
        <div class="col-sm-9 col-sm-offset-3 col-md-10 col-md-offset-2 main">
            <?php 
                /* Exemplo de renderização do conteúdo da página requisitada
                *  Irá variar de acordo com o framework ou componentes que você está utilizando na sua aplicação.
                */
                echo $this->content; 
            ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Um arquivo apenas com o conteúdo da página `projects`:

```
<h1>Página Projects</h1>
<div class="container-fluid">Component HTML</div>
```

Um arquivo apenas com o conteúdo da página `clients`:

```
<h1>Página Clients</h1>
<div class="container-fluid">Component HTML</div>
```

Comment: Sua resposta termina onde eu estou com dificuldades. No seu exemplo o HTML de cada componente **não possui** as demais tags (`<html>`, `<head>` e etc). Um componente escrito nesses moldes, só funcionaria **exatamente** igual quando parte da Aplicação principal, seguindo o exemplo dado, se violássemos a semântica e inseríssemos o CSS/JS do Bootstrap diretamente no `<body>` ao invés de no `<head>`. Além disso, casos específicos, como os que envolvem scripts que precisam ser carregados no `<head>`poderiam não funcionar como esperado isoladamente pois o componente não teria sua tag própria.

Comment: Os componentes não devem possuir as tags (`<html>`, `<head>` e etc), pois a ideia é que cada componente seja injetado, de acordo com a requisição, em um layout padrão da sua aplicação. Caso você queira adicionar outras bibliotecas dependendo do componente requisitado, você pode pensar em uma solução que faça o carregamento das bibliotecas no seu HTML de acordo com a requisição ou, em alguns casos, criar um layout que inclua as bibliotecas necessárias.

Comment: Mas isso eu sei, afinal é a mínima noção sobre modularização de HTML aprendida ao trabalhar com querystrings. A pergunta em si não é sobre a criação de um componente e sim sobre manter o HTML da aplicação principal válido, semântico, quando "plugar" os módulos à ela **sem impedir** que tais componentes funcionem isoladamente, que tanto quanto pude encontrar de informação, é a base do HMVC. Se eu remover as tags "supérfluas" dos componentes, parte da característica deles no meio HMVC se perde, pois eles não serão sozinhos o que são combinados com a Aplicação consumidora.